# How to Select X, SUM (X)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Lets say I have a table like this:

```
ID_COMPANY   ID_EMPLOYEE  SALARY
COMP0001     EMP0001      200
COMP0001     EMP0002      100
COMP0001     EMP0003      300
COMP0002     EMP0001      200
COMP0002     EMP0003      200
COMP0003     EMP0002      200
```

I want to add a column to my table so it can `SUM` salary from based on `ID_Employee` like this:

```
ID_COMPANY   ID_EMPLOYEE  SALARY  TOTAL
COMP0001     EMP0001      200     400
COMP0001     EMP0002      100     300
COMP0001     EMP0003      300     500
COMP0002     EMP0001      200     400
COMP0002     EMP0003      200     500
COMP0003     EMP0002      200     300
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pre-calculate amounts groupped by employee in CTE and then join that CTE in your query:

```
;with cte_Totals as
(
    select ID_EMPLOYEE, sum(SALARY) as TOTAL
    from your_table
    group by ID_EMPLOYEE
)
select 
    ID_COMPANY, 
    ID_EMPLOYEE, 
    SALARY,
    T1.TOTAL
from your_Table as T
    left outer join cte_Totals as T1 on T1.ID_EMPLOYEE = T.ID_EMPLOYEE
```

Comment: don't you think, using partition by is a better idea. Like this 
Select *, SUM(Salary) Over (Partition by ID_employee) Total
From YourTable

Answer (score 2):

```
select id_employee, sum(salary) from [table] group by id_employee
```

This will not 'add' the column to the table, but will output the result. Since this data would change if a new record is added it would be better to generate it dynamically with a query. If you must store it, you should store the result in a materialized view or a temporary table, not add the column to the original table.

Comment: You dont understand what I mean. I want to show 4 Column like my case. If only show `id_employee` and `SUM(salary)`, I can do that correctly

Comment: You can join back to the original table, as @DeadlyJesus answered below.

Answer (score 0):

You can `Join` the table to itself and use one of them to do the `SUM`:

```
SELECT ID_COMPANY, ID_EMPLOYEE, SALARY, sub.SumSalary
FROM Table t JOIN (SELECT ID_EMPLOYEE, SUM(SALARY) as SumSalary
                   FROM Table
                   GROUP BY ID_EMPLOYEE) sub ON t.ID_EMPLOYEE = sub.ID_EMPLOYEE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select *, SUM(Salary) Over (Partition by ID_employee) Total
From YourTable
```